# How to add a View with bindable property inside ContentPage?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I need to display a listview which will contain lists of variable sizes like the following:

```
listview item1: Item1 Item2 Item3
listview item2: Item1 Item2
listview item2: Item1 Item2 Item3 Item4
```

etc

is there a way to create a custom View which can be bound to lists so I would use it like this:

```
<ViewCell>
  <local:CustomView BindableProperty="{Binding listForThisCell}" />
</ViewCell>
```

I really can't find an appropriate example anywhere.

managed to get it working with the following code

```
namespace AppNamespace
{
    public partial class ItemsView : StackLayout
    {
        public ItemsView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public static readonly BindableProperty ItemsListProperty =
                BindableProperty.Create(nameof(ItemsList),
                                        typeof(List<Item>),
                                        typeof(ItemsView),
                                        default(List<Item>));

        public List<Item> ItemsList
        {
            get { return (List<Item>)GetValue(ItemsListProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ItemsListProperty, value); }
        }

        protected override void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (propertyName == ItemsListProperty.PropertyName)
            {
                foreach (Item comment in ItemsList)
                {
                    Children.Add(new ItemView(comment));
                }
            }
            base.OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        }
    }
}
```

xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<StackLayout xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="AppNamespace.ItemsView">
</StackLayout>
```

But is it ok to add children in OnPropertyChanged method? Should it be done somewhere else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could declare `BindableProperty` in your `CustomView.cs`:

```
    public static readonly BindableProperty ListForCurrentCellProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create(nameof(ListForCurrentCell),
                                    typeof(IList<object>),
                                    typeof(CustomView),
                                    default(IList<object>));

    public IList<object> ListForCurrentCell
    {
        get { return (IList<object>)GetValue(ListForCurrentCellProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ListForCurrentCellProperty, value); }
    }
```

And then you will be able to bind collection of items to your property from XAML.

Comment: your code works, but where should I add children etc? I put that code in OnPropertyChanged (edits above), is it ok? And I can't get it to update when the property changes even if I use ObservableCollection..., am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Usually all business logic is placed on view model. `ItemsView` is UI and it should only show data that comes from view model. `<local:ItemsView ItemsList="{Binding Items}" />` and your model `SomeBiggerItem` will has property `List<Item> Items`.